# color output for the .mk file $(info definition

Tags: php, android, makefile, output

I've been trying to get the output of `dumpvar.mk` to print in color like the rest of our build output but `dumpvar` is printing with `$(info rather than echo -e ${color}`

```
$(info SUPERUSER_EMBEDDED=$(SUPERUSER_EMBEDDED))
```

my other makefiles will print the output with commands like:

```
echo -e ${CL_CYN}"SUPERUSER_EMBEDDED=$SUPERUSER_EMBEDDED"${CL_RST}
```

what would be the best way to script this so that dumpvar will print the info in color?

```
ifneq ($(PRINT_BUILD_CONFIG),)
HOST_OS_EXTRA:=$(shell python -c "import platform; print(platform.platform())")
$(info ============================================)
$(info   PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=$(PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME))
$(info   PLATFORM_VERSION=$(PLATFORM_VERSION))
$(info   TARGET_PRODUCT=$(TARGET_PRODUCT))
$(info   TARGET_PRODUCT_VERSION=$(PRODUCT_VERSION))
$(info   TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=$(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT))
$(info   TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=$(TARGET_BUILD_TYPE))
$(info   TARGET_BUILD_APPS=$(TARGET_BUILD_APPS))
$(info   TARGET_ARCH=$(TARGET_ARCH))
$(info   TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=$(TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT))
$(info   TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=$(TARGET_CPU_VARIANT))
$(info   TARGET_GCC_VERSION=$(TARGET_GCC_VERSION))
ifneq ($(TARGET_KERNEL_CUSTOM_TOOLCHAIN),)
$(info   TARGET_KERNEL_CUSTOM_TOOLCHAIN=$(TARGET_KERNEL_CUSTOM_TOOLCHAIN))
ifneq ($(TARGET_KERNEL_CUSTOM_EABI),)
$(info   TARGET_KERNEL_CUSTOM_EABI=$(TARGET_KERNEL_CUSTOM_EABI))
endif
else
$(info   TARGET_TOOLCHAIN=$(ARM_EABI_TOOLCHAIN))
endif
$(info   SUPERUSER_EMBEDDED=$(SUPERUSER_EMBEDDED))
$(info   HOST_ARCH=$(HOST_ARCH))
$(info   HOST_OS=$(HOST_OS))
$(info   HOST_OS_EXTRA=$(HOST_OS_EXTRA))
$(info   HOST_BUILD_TYPE=$(HOST_BUILD_TYPE))
$(info   BUILD_ID=$(BUILD_ID))
$(info   BUILD_NUMBER=$(BUILD_NUMBER))
$(info   OUT_DIR=$(OUT_DIR))
ifneq ($(USE_CCACHE),)
ifneq ($(CCACHE_DIR),)
$(info   CCACHE_DIR=$(CCACHE_DIR))
else
CCACHE_DIR := .ccache
$(info   CCACHE_DIR=$(CCACHE_BASEDIR)$(CCACHE_DIR))
$(info   CCACHE_BASE_DIR=$(CCACHE_BASEDIR))
endif
endif
$(info ============================================)
```

the goal is to add some color definition to the output and make it more readable

in my Makefile i have the colors defined as:

```
ifneq ($(BUILD_WITH_COLORS),0)
  CL_RED="\033[31m"
  CL_GRN="\033[32m"
  CL_YLW="\033[33m"
  CL_BLU="\033[34m"
  CL_MAG="\033[35m"
  CL_CYN="\033[36m"
  CL_RST="\033[0m"
endif
```

Comment: Where do `CL_CYN` and `CL_RST` come from and what are their contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo -e` isn't doing anything magical it just transforms "escape sequences" into the raw output that the terminal then interprets.

`\e` is <kbd>escape</kbd> (which is `^[` as you can see from `echo -e '\e' | cat -v`), etc.

That being said you don't need to go through escape sequences if you can output the raw codes directly.

The `tput` command does that (by looking up the correct codes for your current terminal) for the control sequence you request.

So assuming `CL_CYN` is something like `\e[36m` then the relevant `tput` command would be `tput setaf 6` (to set the foreground command to color 6).

`tput` outputs the raw sequence so any way you can get that to the display will work. So you can embed that directly in `$(info)` calls and it will work.

```
$(info $(shell tput setaf 6)Foo Bar$(shell tput sgr0))
```

`sgr0` is turn off all attributes (reset the colors back to defaults, etc.).

```
CL_RED=$(shell tput setaf 1)
CL_CYN=$(shell tput setaf 6)
CL_RST=$(shell tput sgr0)
$(info $(CL_CYN)FOO $(CL_RED)BAR$(CL_RST))
```

Comment: that's perfect, exactly what i was trying to do

Comment: You can store the result of those shell commands in your `CL_` variables instead of the escape strings and then use them just the same as well.

Comment: stored like CL_CYN="$(shell tput setaf 6)"? ive tried muliple combinations of this without much success

Comment: Yes only without quotes. They aren't needed in the shell (though the shell drops them) and they aren't needed in make (and make leaves them there). What about that wasn't working?

Comment: both CL_CYN=$(shell tput setaf 6) and CL_CYN="$(shell tput setaf 6)" don't give a colored output when used with $(info   $(CL_CYN)FOO. the result is just white unless i add the color def directly like $(info   $(shell tput setaf 6)FOO

Comment: The bit I added to my answer works here. What shell are you using? What does `$(info $(shell printf '$(CL_CYN)' | xxd))` output? What about `$(info $(shell tput setaf 6 | xxd))`?

Comment: this being used in an android build env, colors are defined in my build Makefile and being used in dumpvar.mk. running on ubuntu gnome 14.04. i'll have to give that a go when i boot back up in the morning for work

Comment: You are sure the variable assignments are making it into `dumpvar.mk` correctly?

Comment: ive tried defining them in dumpvar directly and still no dice

Comment: i solved this issue by moving all build color definitions including others not used in this scenario into a new colors.mk file and then including the file when the build info display is called